# Iterate over blocks and get input element values Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to iterate through Block values on Qualtrics.  It contains the following structure:

```
    <div class="BlockOuter">
   <div id="block_43557007" class="Block Standard">
      <div class="BlockHeader">
         <span>CB_3</span>
         <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="QuestionsDiv">
         <div class="Question" id="QID12">
            <div class="SelectBorder">
               <div class="QuestionStructure">
                  <div class="QuestionInfoBar">
                     <div class="QuestionInfoBarInner">
                        <div class="QuestionNumber" style="font-size: 13px;">CB_3</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="QuestionCanvas Skin OutlineMode">
                     <div>
                        <div class="QuestionText_Edit">
                           <div class="QuestionText" id="QuestionText_q33690646_EN" title="Who is Cesar Chavez?" ng-non-bindable="true">Who is Cesar Chavez?</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="InfoBarButtons"><a class="Button " clickcallback="BaseQuestion.clearAll:q33690646($evt,true)">Clear</a></div>
                        <div class="InlineGrade">
                           <div class="choice-row">
                              <input class="form-control GradeInput GradePositive" size="1" value="1" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="1" validation="Number">
                              <span>
                                 <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionPositive" id="ch230074" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                                    <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Labor and farm worker advocate</span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="choice-row">
                              <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="2" validation="Number">
                              <span>
                                 <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch3336258" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="2" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                                    <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="2" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Salsa dancer</span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="choice-row">
                              <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="3" validation="Number">
                              <span>
                                 <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch92975033" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="3" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                                    <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="3" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Television personality</span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                           <div class="choice-row">
                              <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="4" validation="Number">
                              <span>
                                 <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch7917009" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="4" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                                    <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="4" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Former Mexican president</span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="Question" id="QID13">
            <div class="SelectBorder">
               <div class="QuestionStructure">
                  <div class="QuestionInfoBar">
                     <div class="QuestionInfoBarInner">
                        <div class="QuestionNumber" style="font-size: 11px;">CB_3_con</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="QuestionCanvas Skin OutlineMode">
                     <div>
                        <div class="QuestionText_Edit">
                           <div class="QuestionText" id="QuestionText_q76664205_EN" title="Please indicate how confident you are in the above answer" ng-non-bindable="true">Please indicate how confident you are in the above answer</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="InfoBarButtons"><a title="Hold alt key to reverse code, plz" class="Button " clickcallback="BaseQuestion.scoreAll:q76664205($evt,null,true)">Auto</a></div>
                        <div class="InlineGrade">
                           <div class="choice-row">
                              <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q76664205" choiceid="1" validation="Number">
                              <span>
                                 <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch74193948" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q76664205" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                                    <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q76664205" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">My confidence</span></div>
                                 </div>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="BlockShadow"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an image of what the block looks like:

[image]

Here is a link to a jsfiddle (although without CSS) - https://jsfiddle.net/0LLabezt/

I am trying to do the following:

1. Iterate over all the "BlockOuter" divs
2. Grab the value of QuestionNumber class (in this case CB_3, and store in `var = question_label.` . So long as question_label doesn't contain the string "con", move on.
3. Iterate over all the elements in the div .choice-row, and look for the one that contains the value of "1."
4. For just the .choice-row which contains the value of one, find the corresponding div "ScoreSelectionText" and store that in a variable.

I would then like to output those values to the console (or a .csv) where question_label is printed followed by the ScoreSelectionText string value.

I am new to Javascript/Jquery, so I'm very lost.  Here was my attempt at it:

```
$(".BlockOuter").each(function(){
  $(this).find(".QuestionNumber").each(function(){
      var question_label = $(this).text();
      $(this).find(".choice-row").each(function(){
        $(this).find("input").each(function(){
          if($(this).val() ==1){
            var checker = 1;
        }

        if (checker == 1){
          console.log(question_label);
          console.log($(this).find(".ScoreSelectionText").val());
      }

});
```

In this case, I would like the resulting output to be:

{CB_3, "Labor and farm worker advocate"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from `.closest('.QuestionStructure')` .. I think this code will help

```js
$(".BlockOuter").each(function(){
  $(this).find(".QuestionNumber").each(function(){   //<<< here
      var question_label = $(this).text();
      $(this).closest('.QuestionStructure').find(".choice-row").each(function(){
        $(this).find("input").each(function(){
          if($(this).val() == 1){
            console.log(question_label);
            console.log($(this).closest('.choice-row').find(".ScoreSelectionText").text());
          }
        });
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="BlockOuter">
<div id="block_43557007" class="Block Standard">
<div class="BlockHeader">
<span>CB_3</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="QuestionsDiv">
<div class="Question" id="QID12">
<div class="SelectBorder">
<div class="QuestionStructure">
<div class="QuestionInfoBar">
   <div class="QuestionInfoBarInner">
      <div class="QuestionNumber" style="font-size: 13px;">CB_3</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="QuestionCanvas Skin OutlineMode">
   <div>
      <div class="QuestionText_Edit">
         <div class="QuestionText" id="QuestionText_q33690646_EN" title="Who is Cesar Chavez?" ng-non-bindable="true">Who is Cesar Chavez?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="InfoBarButtons"><a class="Button " clickcallback="BaseQuestion.clearAll:q33690646($evt,true)">Clear</a></div>
      <div class="InlineGrade">
         <div class="choice-row">
            <input class="form-control GradeInput GradePositive" size="1" value="1" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="1" validation="Number">
            <span>
               <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionPositive" id="ch230074" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                  <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Labor and farm worker advocate</span></div>
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="choice-row">
            <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="2" validation="Number">
            <span>
               <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch3336258" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="2" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                  <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="2" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Salsa dancer</span></div>
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="choice-row">
            <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="3" validation="Number">
            <span>
               <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch92975033" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="3" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                  <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="3" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Television personality</span></div>
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
         <div class="choice-row">
            <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q33690646" choiceid="4" validation="Number">
            <span>
               <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch7917009" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="4" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                  <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q33690646" p1="4" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">Former Mexican president</span></div>
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="Question" id="QID13">
<div class="SelectBorder">
<div class="QuestionStructure">
<div class="QuestionInfoBar">
   <div class="QuestionInfoBarInner">
      <div class="QuestionNumber" style="font-size: 11px;">CB_3_con</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="QuestionCanvas Skin OutlineMode">
   <div>
      <div class="QuestionText_Edit">
         <div class="QuestionText" id="QuestionText_q76664205_EN" title="Please indicate how confident you are in the above answer" ng-non-bindable="true">Please indicate how confident you are in the above answer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="InfoBarButtons"><a title="Hold alt key to reverse code, plz" class="Button " clickcallback="BaseQuestion.scoreAll:q76664205($evt,null,true)">Auto</a></div>
      <div class="InlineGrade">
         <div class="choice-row">
            <input class="form-control GradeInput" size="1" value="#" questionid="q76664205" choiceid="1" validation="Number">
            <span>
               <div class="SelectionContainer SelectionNeutral" id="ch74193948" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q76664205" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring">
                  <div class="ScoreSelection" clickcallback="BaseQuestion.toggleGrade" instanceid="q76664205" p1="1" p2="" p3="" title="Click to toggle scoring"><span class="ScoreSelectionText">My confidence</span></div>
               </div>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="BlockShadow"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** please keep eyes on console for errors .. you missed more of `});`

Comment: @Parseltongue simple is that .. I just update the `ScoreSelectionText` with `question_label` but if you need the text you need to remove `question_label` from `.text(question_label)` .. `.val()` for inputs,selects .. others use `.text()` not `.val()`

Comment: @Parseltongue my answer and even your question code doesn't print out any `question_label` you need to search the line of your code which cause that .. I think this line will be in another part of code

Comment: Thank you so much, Mohamed.  I got it to work!  Quick question -- what is your workflow for testing your code?  I have to inject Jquery into a webpage, and mess around in the Chrome Inspector, and it feels like such an inelegant way to test things.

Comment: @Parseltongue yes this my way to test my code .. I'm always using chrome Inspector .. so if your editor doesn't gives you the errors for sure the inspector will do that .. You're totally welcome and have a great day :-)